# escalations zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Подскажите, почему заббикс при таких настройках экшена, которые как я думаю должны отправлять удаленную команду каждые 120 секунд, на деле отправляет ее почти рандомно. Т.е чаще раз в 2 минуты и в Actions log видно, что нет никакой последовательности выполнения этого экшена.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сорян, Step duration поменял на 0. Дабы использовал значение по умолчанию указанное в 120 секунд.

Comment: Так же экшн не привязан ни к какому триггеру. Нужно, чтобы заббикс просто отправлял команду рестарта сервиса, путем обращения curl к api. К хосту тоже никакой привязки нет. Команда выполняется, но периоды с которой хотелось бы, чтобы она выполнялась абсолютно не те.

Answer (score 0):

На данном скрине показано действие, которое выполняется сразу же, после срабатывания триггера ( immediately) и следующий шаг в этом действии выполнится через 120 секунд (если он есть).  Если триггер будет срабатывать каждые 5 секунд, то и сообщение будет отсылать каждые 5 секунд. 
Если нужно, чтобы сообщения отправлялись спустя 120 секунд, после срабатывания триггера- поменяйте нумерацию шага (сделать его вторым по счету) и дефолтную длительность.